# Получить значение ячеек определенной строки таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некая таблица:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="number">1</td>
    <td class="code">С224628</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" class="uk-form-width-mini count"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="number">2</td>
    <td class="code">С231903</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" class="uk-form-width-mini count"></td>
</tr>
```

Сделал обработчик:

```
 $('.count').keyup(function() {
   //....
 });
```

Каким образом можно получить значения всех элементов `<td>` строчки, где сработало событие `keyup`? Т.е. был ввод в инпут второй строчки, нужны все значения этой (второй) строчки таблицы.

Comment: значения с number и code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например вот. Получаем значения ячеек, которые находятся в одном `tr` с нпутом, который изменяется.

```js
$('.table').on('input', '.count', function(e) {
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
       number = $(tr).find('.number').text(),
       code = $(tr).find('.code').text();
   console.log(number + ' | ' + code);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="number">1</td>
    <td class="code">С224628</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" class="uk-form-width-mini count"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="number">2</td>
    <td class="code">С231903</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" class="uk-form-width-mini count"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: вместо parents лучше closest

Comment: это да, `parents` всех родителей подходящих вернёт а `closest` только одного ближайшего. Если я правильно понимаю.